# How to update scrollHeight inside onScroll method

Tags: reactjs

For ul element I set method for onScroll={ this.updateListOnScroll } event.
Inside method I'm update my list by concat with new array. 
Then the scrollHeight property increased to new value, but inside my method it still old. 
So the question, how to get new, updated scrollHeight value.

```
  <ul
        className={css.root}
        onScroll={ this.updateListOnScroll }
        >
  </ul>
    updateListOnScroll = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.scrollHeight); (865)
        if (e.target.scrollTop === 0) {
            console.log(e.target.scrollHeight); (865)
            this.props.getMessages();
        }
    };
```

I can't find the way why it doesn't update because by this.props.getMessages();
I get new array and new element.scrollHeight with value 1715.
if select element exactly from browser the value as expected is:
document.querySelector(".MessagesList__root").scrollHeight
1715

Here I add my full components MessagesList with messages
And MessagesContainer that update array by concat old array with new:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import EventBus from '../../api/EventBus';
import socket from '../../api/socket';
import MessagesList from "../MessagesList";
import MessagesForm from "../MessagesForm";

import classNames from 'classnames';
import css from "./MessagesContainer.styl"


export default class MessagesContainer extends Component {

    static propTypes = {

    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        EventBus.subscribe('authorized_success', this.getMessages);
        EventBus.subscribe('messages_list', this.updateMessagesList);

        this.state = {
            list: null,
            nextPage: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const {
            wsToken,
            process
        } = this.props;

        socket.init(
            'ws://crm-ws-devices-m01.dev01.mcemcw.com/ws/v1/devices/messages/',
            wsToken,
            process
        );
    }

    getMessages = () => {
        socket.send(
            'messages_list',
            {
                paginate_by: 10,
                page: (this.state.nextPage === null) ? 1 : this.state.nextPage
            }
        );
    };

    // getPreviousPageMessages = () => {
    //     socket.send(
    //         'messages_list',
    //         {
    //             paginate_by: 10,
    //             page: this.state.nextPage
    //         }
    //     );
    //     EventBus.subscribe('messages_list', this.updateMessagesList);
    // }

    updateMessagesList = (params) => {
        const {
            list,
            nextPage
        } = this.state;

        const {
            data,
            paginate
        } = params;


        let newList = data;
        if (nextPage && nextPage >= 2) {
            newList = list.concat(...data);
        }

        this.setState({
            list: newList,
            nextPage: paginate.next_page
        });
    };

    addNewMessage = (message) => {
        const newList = this.state.list;

        newList.push(message);

        this.setState({
            list: newList
        })
    };

    sendMessage = (message) => {
        socket.send(
            'new_message',
            {
                msg: message
            }
        );

        EventBus.subscribe('new_message', this.addNewMessage);
    };

    render () {
        const { list } = this.state;
        if (!list) {
            return 'Loading...';
        }

        return (
            <div className={css.root}>
                <MessagesList
                    getMessages={this.getMessages}
                    list={list}
                />
                <div className={classNames(css.root__form,{
                    [css.form_emptymessage] : this.state.isEmptyMessage,
                    [css.form_longmessage] : this.state.isTooLongMessage
                })}>
                    <MessagesForm
                        sendMessage={this.sendMessage}
                        markAllNewAsRead={this.markAllNewAsRead}
                        placeholderWriteMessage={this.props.t.write_message}
                        tooLongMessage={this.props.t.characters_limit_exceeded}
                        isEmptyMessage={this.props.t.is_empty}
                        sendingAdvice={this.props.t.sendingAdvice}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

---

```
import React, {Component} from "react";

import chatSocket from "../../api/socket.js";
import MessagesItem from "../MessagesItem";

import css from "./MessagesList.styl";

export default class MessagesList extends Component {

    static propTypes = {

    };

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.listRef = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
            listHeight: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let listContainer = this.listRef.current;
        listContainer.scrollTop = listContainer.scrollHeight;
    }

    /**
     * Sort messages
     * @param messages
     * @returns {*}
     */
    sortMessages = (list) => {
        list.sort(function (a, b) {
            return new Date( b.sended ).getTime() - new Date( a.sended ).getTime();
        });
        return list;
    }


    updateListOnScroll = (e) => {
        if (e.target.scrollTop === 0) {
            console.log(e.target.scrollHeight);
            this.props.getMessages();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Added today and yesterday separator items
     * @param messages
     * @returns {Array}
     */
    formatMessages = (list) => {
        var today = new Date();
        today.setHours(0);
        today.setMinutes(0);
        today.setSeconds(0);

        var yesterday = new Date();
        yesterday.setHours(0);
        yesterday.setMinutes(0);
        yesterday.setSeconds(0);
        yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);

        var laterList = [];
        var yesterdayList = [];
        var todayList = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (new Date( list[i].sended ).getTime() < (yesterday.getTime() / 1000)) {
                laterList.push(list[i]);
                console.log("later");
            } else if (new Date( list[i].sended ).getTime() < (today.getTime() / 1000)) {
                yesterdayList.push(list[i]);
                console.log("yesterday");
            } else {
                todayList.push(list[i]);
                console.log("today");
            }
        }

        var result = [];

        if (laterList.length) {
            result = laterList;
        }

        if (yesterdayList.length) {
            if (result.length) {
                result.push({yesterday: true, id: 'yesterday'});
            }
            result = result.concat(yesterdayList);
        }

        if (todayList.length) {
            if (result.length) {
                result.push({today: true, id: 'today'});
            }
            result = result.concat(todayList);
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare messages (sort and format)
     * @param messages
     * @returns {Array.<T>}
     */
    prepareMessages = (list) => {
        list = this.sortMessages(list);
        list = list.reverse();

        return this.formatMessages(list);
    }

    render () {
        const { list } = this.props;
        return (
            <ul
            className={css.root}
            ref={this.listRef}
            onScroll={ this.updateListOnScroll }
            >
                {
                    this.prepareMessages(list).map((item, index) => {
                        /* destructured id, spred operator ...propsExceptId */
                        if (item.today) {
                            return (
                                <div key="today" className="text-center message-day">
                                    <span className="message-day-text">{this.props.t.today}</span>
                                </div>
                            );
                        }
                        if (item.yesterday) {
                            return (
                                <div key="yesterday" className="text-center message-day">
                                    <span className="message-day-text">{this.props.t.yesterday}</span>
                                </div>
                            );
                        }
                        return (
                            <MessagesItem
                                key={index}
                                item={item}
                            />
                        );
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the complete component code? I find it hard to make sense of the code you have shared, seems like it's missing relevant parts

Comment: `Then the scrollHeight property increased to new value, but inside my method it still old` - Please post the relevant code. How do you know that `scrollHeight` was increased? You could simulate the actual work with mocked data increasing on scroll.

Comment: Ok. Going to update my question tomorrow.